# Why can't I use "wide" as variable name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I define a new class like this:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject {
    int wide;
}
- (id)initWithWide:(int)value;
@end
```

When I implement it the initWithWide method like this:

```
@implementation SomeClass
- (id)initWithWide:(int)value  {
    self = [super init];
    wide = value;
}
@end
```

Xcode show me the error: `"Expected identifier or'('"`. When I change the "wide" variable name to else, It's OK. So it look like I can't use "wide" as variable name in Objective-C?

#### Renamed wide so  THIS works ok btw:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject {
    int wide1;
}
- (id)initWithWide:(int)value; 
@end

@implementation SomeClass
- (id)initWithWide:(int)value  {
    self = [super init];
    wide1 = value;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed 'wide' is a problem. I have edited the question. I couldn't really believe it either

### BUT

wide is typedef'd on OSX / iOS (MacTypes.h lines ~ 133)

```
struct wide {
  UInt32              lo;
  SInt32              hi;
};
typedef struct wide                     wide;
```

---

#### anyway this is more advice then answer BUT

it doesn't make sense to name a variable wide ;) It shouldn't be just some adjective in this case -- Name it width!

Comment: You are right (and I withdraw my previous comments). Actually I made an error when testing this problem. MacTypes.h is included even on iOS, so you have found the problem.